# Defining dialect of lang attribute in HTML

Tags: html

When using the lang attribute in HTML, what is the purpose of declaring the Dialect (NOT the language)?
for example: what is the difference between

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

and

```
<html lang="en-GB">
```

Comment: The difference is that `en-US` declares US English, whereas `en-UK` is invalid (United Kingdom is `GB`). Generally subcodes define versions of languages. If you are asking about *purpose*, you should first clarify what you expect the purpose(s) of declaring language in the first place to be. For some of the purposes (which are mostly imaginary/theoretical), subcodes may matter.

Comment: I can see the purpose of defining the language , But I can't see the importance of declaring the Dialect, and that is where my question comes!

Comment: It only matters if you write code for it to matter.

Answer (score 2):

w3.org provides several uses of the lang attribute here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

- Assisting search engines
- Assisting speech synthesizers
- Helping a user agent select glyph variants for high quality typography
- Helping a user agent choose a set of quotation marks
- Helping a user agent make decisions about hyphenation, ligatures, and spacing
- Assisting spell checkers and grammar checkers

In your particular example, the difference between American English and British English might be for instance used by a speech synthesizer often used by blind people.

Comment: The list quotes is mostly a theoretical wishlist, or a description of what might happen (but mostly just hasn’t happened).